# Right outer join with derived table in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Simple enough query.... I've done it before in SQL I feel like but having trouble in Access.

```
CREATE TABLE Users (UserID Text, UserName Text)

CREATE TABLE Ages (UserID Text, Age Integer)

INSERT INTO Users (UserID,UserName) VALUES ('A','John')

INSERT INTO Users (UserID,UserName) VALUES ('B','Jane')
```

I want a query that returns all User IDs and UserNames regardless of whether or not there is an entry for them in the Ages table. When I try the following query, I get no rows returned:

```
SELECT T1.UserID, T1.UserName, T2.AGE 
FROM (SELECT UserID, UserName FROM Users) AS T1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT UserID, Age FROM Ages) AS T2 
ON T1.UserID = T2.UserID
```

I would expect to see two rows and three columns from the above query, with the age value being null for both rows. Instead I just get no rows back.

I know I don't need to use a derived table for T1 in the example above but I'm doing it to make it easier for some where clauses I need to apply to both derived tables in the real query I'm trying to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b7390/1) is a SQL Fiddle that shows an empty result set with your query (using SQL Server rather than Access, so the `text` type needed to be changed to `varchar()`).

Here is a query with a `left outer join` that does what you want:

```
SELECT u.UserID, u.UserName, a.AGE 
FROM (SELECT UserID, UserName FROM Users) AS u left outer join
     (SELECT UserID, Age FROM Ages) AS a
     ON u.UserID = a.UserID;
```

Remember:  a `left outer join` keeps all the rows in the first table; a `right outer join` keeps all the rows in the second table.

Comment: 1+ for the fiddle link.

Comment: Thanks that did it. Was confused on right vs left outer join!

Answer (score 0):

The way you have described your desired results is not how a `RIGHT JOIN` works.

A `RIGHT JOIN` will use the 'right side' (the selected columns from `Ages`) as the primary table, and join matching rows from the 'left side' substituting a NULL where the left side has no match.  this means that you can never have results from the right side that aren't *already in the right side*. Since your 'right side' has no rows (containing data or NULL entries), there isn't anything to compare against when joining with the left side.  As such, you will correctly see no results returned.